# Flagging questions as off-topic

Tags: feature-request, flagging, migration

When flagging a question as off-topic we are given a choice between either completely off-topic, belongs to meta, or belongs to stats.SE.

Is it possible to add another option "Belong elsewhere on the SE network" which may or may not include a free-text form to suggest where it might belong (a programming/CS theory/etc. question)?

Edit: Also, please suggest below what other options may be desireable as migration targets.

Edit: It's been about two months now, and we can only still suggest migration to stats and meta.

Comment: not an answer: but for the time being, you can suggest one by flagging the question for moderator attention. Mods can migrate questions anywhere.

Comment: Willie, I know that. However seeing there is half the feature implemented already I figured it's worth the request.

Comment: oh, I do not disagree. I was just proposing an interim work-around while our overlords sort this out. :)

Comment: Pathways for migration (by non-mods) have to be "unlocked" by the SE team, I think—my understanding was that they would unlock the paths that seemed to be getting used or would be used or some such.

Answer (score 11):

cstheory.stackexchange.com and physics.stackexchange.com seem to be targets that may be nice to have for suggested migrations.

Comment: Hi. We haven't had a problem with questions migrated from Math.SE to cstheory so far but we have had some problems with questions migrated from other SE sites. I think is not easy for a general user to judge if a questions is a *research-level* questions in tcs (I think most users of Math.SE are not theoretical computer scientists), and this may cause non-research-level questions being migrated to cstheory. We haven't discussed it on cstheory but my personal preference is to keep the moderators in charge unless we find away to make sure that non-research-level tcs questions don't get

Comment: migrated to cstheory by users not familiar with the topic.

Comment: @Kaveh: noted. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Willie and Isaac covered these in the comments, but I thought this deserved a full answer.

We can unlock migration paths when there is a significant need for them.  Looking at the outgoing migrations, only a handful each have gone to Physics and Stack Overflow.  CSTheory and TeX haven't seen a handful of migrations combined.

You are able to flag the question indicating that it belongs elsewhere and leaving a note for the moderators as to where the question should go.  If the mods are noticing that a significant number of questions are going somewhere, then we can evaluate whether a migration path is warranted.